# How to complex the video and gif and make the watermark loop in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I had complex video and gif but the gif was play once time, I also set the loop param , It seem didn't work any more.

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/Download/Test2/test2.mp4 -loop 1 -i /sdcard/Download/Test2/1.gif -loop 1 -i /sdcard/Download/Test2/2.gif -filter_complex [1:v]rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih)[rotete1];[0:v][rotete1]overlay=main_h-overlay_h-10:main_w-overlay_w-10[overlayout1];[2:v]rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih)[rotete2];[overlayout1][rotete2]overlay=20:20[out3] -map [out3] -map 0:a -codec:a copy /sdcard/Download/Test2/output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The GIF demuxer does not recognize the loop option.

For GIFs, if the loop is set in the file, then you can use

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/Download/Test2/test2.mp4
       -ignore_loop 0 -i /sdcard/Download/Test2/1.gif
       -ignore_loop 0 -i /sdcard/Download/Test2/2.gif ...
```

Comment: I also the try ignore_loop but my program seem frozen when I run the code